# Interleave two numpy 1D arrays for stereo audio output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two [numpy float32 arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
a = numpy.array(c)
b = numpy.array(d)
```

and these two represent two mono audio streams.

I'd like to write them to a stereo WAV file using scipy's [wavwrite](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html):

```
scipy.io.wavfile.write(wav_name, sampling_rate, samples)
```

How can I join the two arrays into one `samples` 2-d array, and interleave them in order to get a proper stereo WAV at output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply make sure `a` and `b` are column vectors, and stack them horizontally:

```
 result = np.hstack((a.reshape(-1, 1), b.reshape(-1,1)))
```

Another option, if you know that your arrays are 1D, is to stack vertically and transpose:

```
result = np.vstack((a, b)).T
```

Comment: btw, closing `)` is missing above.

Comment: Thanks! I do that all the time since all the `np.*stack()` function take a tuple of arrays as input instead of multiple inputs. It's a parenthesis-fest :P

Answer (score -1):

I would use numpy.dstack:

```
left = numpy.array(left_data)
right= numpy.array(right_data)
stereo_data=numpy.dstack((left,right))[0]
scipy.io.wavfile.write(stereo_data)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `channels = data.shape[1]` returns 474240, which is the number of samples, should return 2. Seems like the row-column dimensions are understood wrong?

Comment: Not quite - dstack is increasing the dimensionality of the array, so they are [1,n_samples,n_channels].  I have edited the code suggestion to avoid that.